# Why do we have a [beginner] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Meta tags are not allowed, right?

Comment: It does look like [tag:beginner] is trying to, at least, cover a lot of ground, which by itself makes it a potentially poor tag. On the other hand, saying "I'm an expert at helping beginners" isn't *entirely* unreasonable, so it does pass an initial "I'm an expert at X" tag smell test. I haven't fully thought it through, but I'd be inclined to get rid of that tag. But let's see what others think before taking action.

Comment: Looks like [this tag has been partially discussed previously in 2010](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-a-tips-tag-worthwhile/9#9) /cc @MichaelKjörling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, I'll delete the tag later this evening. Unless anyone has a good reason why not?

Comment: I agree it should go.  There are over 80 questions with that tag now, so please give the list a quick skim and retag anything where that's the only tag.  Thanks.